# How to add Image icon on certain buttons?

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, imageicon

I am making a board game and I need to put the player 1 and player 2 pieces on grid of buttons. I am using a image icon to represent the piece which I want to put it on buttons. The problem is that I have a loop of buttons, and I need to put piece1 on buttons 1,3,5,7,9 and piece2 on buttons 2,4,6,8,10.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
    for(int i=0;i<30;i++){
        buttons[i] = new JButton("label"+ i);
        buttons[i].setBackground(Color.white);
        if (i < 10) {
           if (i%2 == 0) {
             buttons[i].setIcon(piece2);
           } else {
             buttons[i].setIcon(piece1);
           }
        }
        panel.add(buttons[i]);
    }
```

Comment: You need to click the check mark on this answer to accept it and give the person who took the time to help you credit.